# Django templates - can `block.super` mean something without `extends`?

Tags: django, django-templates

I saw a template using `{{ block.super }}` (inside `block` tags), **without any `extends` tag anywhere in the file.**

Here it is: https://github.com/RyanBalfanz/django-launch-page/blob/develop/launch_page/templates/launch_page/base.html

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this grabs content from the extended template's block I would say this is more of a placeholder for if it is extended in the future this wouldn't be left out by accident and clobber any preexisting CSS. But as it is right now the tag is pointless.